# How to write a LINQ query with inner join conditions and IN sub query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write a LINQ for the following query,

```
Select DI.iDataItemID, 
DI.iDataTypeID,
DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID
from OT_BackendUpdate_DataItem DI
INNER JOIN OT_BackendUpdate_DataItemStatus DIS ON DIS.iDataItemID = 
DI.iDataItemID 
INNER JOIN OT_BackendUpdate_RefDataItemStatus ON DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID 
= OT_BackendUpdate_RefDataItemStatus.iDataItemStatusID
AND DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID = 1 AND DI.iDataTypeID = 8 and 
DIS.dDateEffective IN (
SELECT Max(dDateEffective) FROM OT_BackendUpdate_DataItemStatus Where 
OT_BackendUpdate_DataItemStatus.iDataItemID = DI.iDataItemID
)
```

My LINQ query is as follows,

```
result = from dataItem in msaDBContext.OT_BackendUpdate_DataItem
         join dataItemStatus in msaDBContext.OT_BackendUpdate_DataItemStatus 
              on dataItem.iDataItemID equals dataItemStatus.iDataItemID
         join refDataItemStatus in msaDBContext.OT_BackendUpdate_RefDataItemStatus 
              on dataItemStatus.iDataItemCurrentStatusID equals refDataItemStatus.iDataItemStatusID
         where dataItemStatus.iDataItemCurrentStatusID == 1 && && dataItem.iDataTypeID == 8
         select new
         {
          iDataItemID = dataItem.iDataItemID,
          iDataItemCurrentStatusID = dataItemStatus.iDataItemCurrentStatusID,
          iDataTypeID = dataItem.iDataTypeID
         };
```

Please let me know how do add the logic to check if the dDateEffective is Max value for the DataItem in the LINQ query. (i.e. the sub query to check the Max(dDateEffective) from the SQL query)

Need to know how to use both "IN" and "MAX" condition in LINQ from the SQL query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linq to sql select inside an inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786382/linq-to-sql-select-inside-an-inner-join)

Comment: @BarrJ Thank you for replying. Could you please let me know, how to use IN and select MAX for my above query.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue with the following query,

```
result = from dataItem in msaDBContext.OT_BackendUpdate_DataItem
     join dataItemStatus in msaDBContext.OT_BackendUpdate_DataItemStatus 
          on dataItem.iDataItemID equals dataItemStatus.iDataItemID
     join refDataItemStatus in msaDBContext.OT_BackendUpdate_RefDataItemStatus 
          on dataItemStatus.iDataItemCurrentStatusID equals refDataItemStatus.iDataItemStatusID
     where dataItemStatus.iDataItemCurrentStatusID == 1 && && dataItem.iDataTypeID == 8 
&& (msaDBContext.OT_BackendUpdate_DataItemStatus.Where(x => x.iDataItemID == dataItem.iDataItemID).Select(x=>x.dDateEffective).Max<DateTime>()
                                     ).Equals(dataItemStatus.dDateEffective)
     select new
     {
      iDataItemID = dataItem.iDataItemID,
      iDataItemCurrentStatusID = dataItemStatus.iDataItemCurrentStatusID,
      iDataTypeID = dataItem.iDataTypeID
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res=(from DI in msaDBContext.OT_BackendUpdate_DataItem
                                .Where(x=>x.iDataTypeID==8)
         join DIS in msaDBContext.OT_BackendUpdate_DataItemStatus
                                 .Where(x=>x.iDataItemCurrentStatusID==1)
                                 .GroupBy(x=>new 
                                             {            
                                              x.iDataItemID,
                                              x.iDataItemCurrentStatusID,
                                              x.dDateEffective
                                             })
                                 .Select(x=>new 
                                            {
                                             iDataItemID=x.key.iDataItemID,
                             iDataItemCurrentStatusID=x.key.iDataItemCurrentStatusID,
                                             dDateEffective=x.Max(y=>y.dDateEffective)
                                             })
         on DI.iDataItemID equals DIS.iDataItemID
         join msaDBContext.OT_BackendUpdate_RefDataItemStatus RDIS
         on DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID equals RDIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID
         select new {DI,DIS})
         .Select(x=>new 
                    {
                      iDataItemID=x.DI.iDataItemID,
                      iDataTypeID=x.DI.iDataTypeID,
                      iDataItemCurrentStatusID=x.DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID
                     }).ToList();
```